# Stop-color in CSS/SVG isn't working

Tags: css, svg

So, I have the following code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="360" height="240">
<style>stop{stop-opacity:1}circle{fill:url(#r)}</style>
<defs>
<radialGradient id="r" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="50%" fy="50%">
<stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#ce1126"/>
<stop offset="17%" style="stop-color:#e5911d"/>
<stop offset="33%" style="stop-color:#fcd116"/>
<stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:#18c063"/>
<stop offset="67%" style="stop-color:#75aadb"/>
<stop offset="83%" style="stop-color:#803ac5"/>
<stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#00335b"/>
</radialGradient>
</defs>
<circle cx="150" cy="300" r="55"/>
</svg>
```

Interestingly enough, if I add `stop-color:attr(c)` to the CSS of the stops and change them accordingly (`style="stop-color:`=>`c="`), it doesn't work (or at least not in Safari/iOS9). Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting that Safari does not support this. This seems to work in Firefox:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="360" height="240">
  <style>
    stop {
      stop-opacity: 1
    }
    circle {
      fill: url(#r)
    }
  </style>
  <defs>
    <radialGradient id="r" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="50%" fy="50%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#ce1126" />
      <stop offset="17%" style="stop-color:#e5911d" />
      <stop offset="33%" style="stop-color:#fcd116" />
      <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:#18c063" />
      <stop offset="67%" style="stop-color:#75aadb" />
      <stop offset="83%" style="stop-color:#803ac5" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#00335b" />
    </radialGradient>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="60" cy="100" r="55" fill="url(#r)" />
</svg>
```

I would not recomend doing it in that way.
The most supported way should be:

- Add stop-color as an attribute
- Add a class or id to the stop element and add a stop-color with css.

Comment: Interesting, seeing as [this website](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_grad_radial.asp) uses the inline styling method. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @SomePerson please don't use "that website" use mozilla documentation its a lot more up to date: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Gradients

Answer (score 0):

This is should be an easy way, which will works in all browsers

```
<stop offset="0%"  style={{ stopColor: '#ce1126' }}/>
<stop offset="17%" style={{ stopColor: '#e5911d' }}/>
<stop offset="33%" style={{ stopColor: '#fcd116' }}/>
<stop offset="50%" style={{ stopColor: '#18c063' }}/>
<stop offset="67%" style={{ stopColor: '#75aadb' }}/>
<stop offset="83%" style={{ stopColor: '#803ac5' }}/>
<stop offset="100%" style={{ stopColor: '#00335b' }}/>
```